# Multiple writes in a relational database

Tags: database

I'm pretty sure that with a relational database, it's faster and better to read 50 records at once than to make 50 calls for one record each. Is there a performance benefit from performing multiple writes all at once? If not, why not?

Comment: Performance aside, you'd be wise to do logically connected writes in a single transaction so if the last insert fails you can easily roll back the entire operation and not leave a bunch of orphaned records.

Comment: Agreed. I'm just trying to get a better sense for "how long things take" and where, in general, you can look when you need to scale your DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably depends on the RDBMS and the storage engine, but at least in MySQL/InnoDB, multiple writes in one transaction (as well the multi-insert syntax, which, afaik, is MySQL extension) allows you not to update non-unique indexes before transaction is commited, and the update of the index happens at once with all new values (since it's a b-tree, in this way its much faster). It's possible that RDBMS optimizes other writes as well, to have sequential instead of random writes.

Also, if there is a table-level locking (as in MyISAM), locking the table once, writting multiple records and then unlocking removes the overhead of lock/unlock for every write.

So generally, there is performance gain, but it depends on the database server used.

Comment: fwiw, multi-row INSERT is standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Doing all your reads at once makes sense, although there are some problems in it which I'll touch on in a minute.

Doing all your writes at once poses a particular problem: the data is in the database until you put it there. If you're waiting for some optimization threshold (let's say 50) then transaction 1 is going to have to wait for (unrelated) transactions 2-50 to complete before it goes to the database. This means that in the mean time (which could be several [seconds, minutes, hours]) nobody knows what those records are, or if they're updated what the new values are. (Same with reads but the other way around. Your data may be out of date by the time you get to use it.)

Performance wise, I cannot imagine that combining writes closer together would not have some performance. (IF that was confusing to read, I meant "You should always get a performance boost by grouping.") If nothing else, you have a better chance to hit memory caches instead of disk caches than if you do them separately. @Darhazer brings up a good point about locking. So strictly from a total-time-spent-writing point of view, it would be better to group them. From an application performance point of view, it's difficult to say without an intricate knowledge of the business requirements of the app.